# Is a vector space with two identical vectors a vector space with one or two vectors?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

I'm new this, and cannot find any answers by searching. If a vector space has 2 identical vectors, in particular the zero vector, is it a vector space with 2 vectors or since they are linearly dependent is it technically condensed to a vector space with just the zero vector?

i.e: Is the vector space $\{0, 0\}$ a vector space with 1 or 2 vectors?

Comment: what is meant by '2 identical vectors'?

Comment: I updated the question with the particular example I was asking about

Comment: @mvw: In standard set theory "$\{0,0\}$" does specify a set, namely $\{x\mid x=0\lor x=0\}$, which happens to be the same set as $\{0\}$. Actually, since most expositions of ZFC have an "unordered pair" axiom, but not a "singleton" axiom, one can argue that formally "$\{0\}$" _is an abbreviation for_ $\{0,0\}$.

Comment: I just had a look at ZFC, interesting that they allow it.

Answer (score 6):

A vector space is a set equipped with a certain structure. As a set, it cannot have "two of the same": $\{0,0\} = \{0\}$ (this is due to the so-called "axiom of extensionality", which states that two sets are the same if they contain the same elements). In particular, a vector space with only the zero vector contains exactly one vector.

Answer (score 1):

No vector space can have two separate zero-vectors, as a consequence of the definition.

Suppose we have two zero vectors $0,0'$ (not necessarily equal).  It follows, by definition of a zero-vector, that
$$
0 + 0' = 0'
$$
However, we also have
$$
0 + 0' = 0' + 0 = 0
$$
It therefore follows that $0 = 0'$. So, the two elements cannot be distinct.

Comment: I am aware of vector spaces having to have different zero vectors but what im asking is if there are duplicates of the same vector does it count as one or two vectors?

Comment: @user220264 a vector space (on top of having other properties) must be a set.  Part of the definition of a set (as Yuval clarifies) states that two equal (identical) elements count only once. Or, more precisely, the sets $\{0,0\}$ and $\{0\}$ are *the same set*, since each element of one is an element of the other.

Comment: @mvw right, but there's a reason we don't give the definition of a vector space as "an abelian group with a scalar product" in introductory linear algebra courses